# Retrieving PHP property name as string

Tags: php

I have some JSON, if I `var_dump` the output looks like:

```
var_dump( $oJSON->{$oQ->sQuestionName} );

object(stdClass)[14]
  public 'Lease' => boolean true
```

I would like to retrieve 'Lease' as a string.

I've tried casting it:

```
(string)$oJSON->{$oQ->sQuestionName}
```

but it returns an `E_RECOVERABLE`:

```
E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

The following works, however I feel there must be a better way?

```
array_shift(array_values(array_keys(get_object_vars($oJSON->{$oQ->sQuestionName}))));
```

N.B. I can't use to use the following due to compatability issues

```
array_keys(get_object_vars($oJSON->{$oQ->sQuestionName}))[0]
```

Comment: *I can't use to use the following due to compatability issues* just split it into two lines.

Comment: yeah I could do that. Assign to a var, then go to first pos. However it feels there must be some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ReflectionClass::getProperties()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) to get a list of the object's properties.

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your desired object to an array first

```
   $array = (array) $oJSON->{$oQ->sQuestionName};
```

Then you can take its first element's key

```
   echo key($array);  // Should say Lease
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/687811)**

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `json_decode` with second parameter `true`

For example:

```
$str = '{"0":{"id":"123","name":"Title"}}';
var_dump(json_decode($str,true));
```

So, you will have an array with string objects.